# $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^{n-1}$ is not retract of $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space

I have to solve the following:

**Show that $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^{n-1}$ is not retract of $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^n$ for $n\geq 2$.**

I have done this with knowledge of homotopy-groups, by showing that $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot factor through $\mathbb{0}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Yet, I would like to know is there some other way to prove that (without using groups of homotopy)?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the power of homotopy groups, to prove things like that. Compare to the problem of proving that the closed unit disc $D^2$ does not retract to its boundary $S^1$; how would you do that withough groups of homotopy?

Comment: For $n$ even, a homology argument (in degree $n-1$) works just as well as the homotopy group argument (and so is arguably more simple), although this does not work for $n$ odd as one only gets that if a retraction $r$ exists then $0\stackrel{i_*}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{r_*}{\to} 0$ is the identity which is not a contradiction.

Comment: For all $n$ you can use the cohomology ring structure which tells you that the ring map $\mathbb Z/2[x]/x^{n+1} \to \mathbb Z/2 [x]/x^n$ has no section.

Comment: @JustinYoung You should turn that into an answer, I think, so that this question has an answer. It certainly gives the OP what they want...

Comment: Or, maybe, it is enough of a hint, since this question sounds like a homework.

Answer (score 3):

One can use the fact that $H^*(\mathbb R P^n, \mathbb Z/2) \cong \mathbb Z/2[x]/x^{n+1}$ as a graded commutative ring, where $x$ is in degree one. The inclusion $\mathbb R P^{n-1} \to \mathbb RP^n$ induces a map of graded rings $\mathbb Z/2[x]/x^{n+1} \to \mathbb Z/2[x]/x^n$. By considering fundamental groups or using  the cell structure one can see easily that $x\mapsto x$, and so the map is the standard quotient map. If there were a retraction $\mathbb R P^{n} \to \mathbb RP^{n-1}$, then that would induce a section $\mathbb Z/2[x]/x^{n} \to \mathbb Z/2[x]/x^{n+1}$ of the quotient map. But, then we would still have $x\mapsto x$, and so $0 = x^n \mapsto x^n \neq 0$, a contradiction.